# cant resolve symbol io when importing io.restassured

Tags: maven, pom.xml, rest-assured

hi i am trying to import the io.restassured dependency but am not sure why i am receiving compilation errors from my main java file

here is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.csg.pbapac.channels.unodux</groupId>
    <artifactId>openshifttraefik-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                <artifactId>rest-assured-all</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20180130</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <source>8</source>
                        <target>8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

and these are my import statements with compile errors

```
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
```

i was able to run `mvnw clean install` with successful build so im not sure what is the issue here

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing  tag for that dependency and I would use this one instead anyways...

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```